# Generate list of post IDs from public fan pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to enumerate posts that are made public? for eg. even without logging into fb, you can see long list of posts in fb.com/pepsi page how can I retrieve them?

I am trying to find a way to enumerate the post IDs from a fan page's wall and loop through them one by one. Because I only know pepsi page's ID, I start from there. I would like to loop through each post ID after enumerating them as a list. Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can still query the Graph API without logging into Facebook but you will need an access token. You can simply create an application and use the `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` as an application access token. I think this should be enough for only dealing with public posts.

A call to - `https://graph.facebook.com/56381779049/posts?access_token=XXX` will return JSON data of the public content of/on that page.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "56381779049_10151643119694050",
         "from": {
            "category": "Food/beverages",
            "name": "Pepsi",
            "id": "56381779049"
         },
         "story": "\"Thanks for sharing Bobby! Love...\" on Bobby Kirchner's photo.",
         ...
         "created_time": "2013-03-29T21:35:41+0000",
         "updated_time": "2013-03-29T21:35:41+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "56381779049_10151639464904050",
         "from": {
            "category": "Food/beverages",
            "name": "Pepsi",
            "id": "56381779049"
         },
         "story": "\"Hi James, sorry to hear that....\" on James Kraus II's photo.",
         ...
         "created_time": "2013-03-27T18:23:49+0000",
         "updated_time": "2013-03-27T18:23:49+0000"
      },
...
```

Depending on what language you are using, it would be simple to iterate over all of the data and convert it into a structure that would be easier to perform analysis. In PHP, for example, there is a `json_decode()` function, that converts JSON data into a normal PHP array.

Note that whenever you make a query to the Facebook API's and there is a relatively large amount of data to be returned, there will be a paging mechanism within each request. It look's like this -

```
"paging": {
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/56381779049/posts?access_token=XXX&limit=25&since=1364592941&__previous=1",
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/56381779049/posts?access_token=XXX&limit=25&until=1362582226"
}
```

Comment: can you please help me **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740168/facing-issue-while-trying-to-send-the-reply-to-facebook-post-in-mvc3)** ?

Comment: **Answer is helpful. Instead of ID of any page you can also use a name of page.**

**`https://graph.facebook.com/SachinTendulkar/posts?access_token=XXX`**